# Sample size RM-ANOVA

Tags: sampling, sample-size, small-sample

I am comparing Shannon entropy values (for zone occupation) obtained by soccer players during small-sided games in three pitch dimensions. I am also scrutinizing differences between expertise level (national- or regional-level players).
So, I used a General Linear Model RM ANOVA, with the within-subject factor being the 3 pitch dimensions and the between-subject factor being expertise (2 levels - national and regional).
I have checked for univariate and multivariate normality and it is okay, but I only have 16 participants (8 regional and 8 national players). Is it ok to perform this test, even if there aren't normality issues.

I also got a significant interaction effect between pitch_dim*expertise. To scrutinize for statistical differences, do you recommend performing an independent t-test with a bootstrap resampling of 1000 (since I only have 8 players per group)?